# Get number of columns in SQLite result

Tags: c++, sql, c, sqlite, d

Well, this should be ultra-simple, but I simply can't seem to spot it among the 1001 sqlite-related commands.

**So :**

- I'm performing a `SELECT` statement, with `sqlite3_prepare`
- I'm getting the results per row with `sqlite3_step`
- I'm accessing the Xth's column's result by `sqlite3_column_text(sqlStmt,X)`

**The question is :**

How can I get the number of *columns* in the row? (= the range in which X can... move...)

---

***P.S.*** The question is tagged with `d` (I'm basically developing in D), but it won't make much difference since it's using native C bindings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/data_count.html,

```
int sqlite3_data_count(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt);
```

returns the number of columns in the current row of the result set of prepared statement
`pStmt`.

Comment: P.S. What I *love* about SO : I could spend hours on looking for one particular command, and testing a few of them (the usual... trial and error...). And you just saved me so much time, I can now use more... productively. Thanks again! (waiting for my... 8 minutes to accept your answer...)